# Cluster Auto Scaler with resources req & lim

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling

This is the first time I deployed Cluster Autoscaler (CA) on EKS.

The CA configuration file contains Limits & Requests:

```
     Limits:                                           
│       cpu:     100m                                                                                         
│       memory:  300Mi                                                                                                                
│    Requests:                                                                                                                       
│       cpu:     100m                                                                                                                 
│       memory:  300Mi
```

My questions are the following:

1. Does the Limits & Requests fields in the CA refers to the CA pod only?
2. If I deploy a pod (for example nginx) and I deploy it without specifying resources requests & limits in the pod's configuration, will the CA know how much resources nginx needs and allocate the proper amount?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html) is your friend:

1. The limits and requests fields in the Cluster Autoscaler (which will basically be a Deployment on k8s)
   definition will be valid for each pod that will be spawned with this
   definition, unless the pods themselves have limits and requests
   defined.
2. Which brings us to your second question: if a pod is spawned based on a config file without
   limits & resources, the defaults will be those specified for the master node.